# Install APK on Android using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

I am trying to install an apk using the following code below, whenever I tried to execute the code, it only shows 'Starting...'. I don't see any notification that the apk is being installed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Uri.parse()`. Use `Uri.fromFile()`. If your answer to that is "it is not a file", then that is your problem -- you need to have the APK as a file, somewhere that the installer can reach it (e.g., external storage).